# Titanium Mobile is not getting correct accuracy on iOS

Tags: javascript, geolocation, gps, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a problem with my coding. My code just doesn't seem to be getting an accuracy lower then 1414.

Whenever I open google maps, and get my location there it finds it usually within a second. If I switch back I see a correct accuracy for a couple of seconds, and then it switches back to the very low accuracy (1414).

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
function reportPosition(e){
    label.text = e.coords.longitude + " - " + e.coords.accuracy;
}

Ti.Geolocation.purpose = "Test";
Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 10;
Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = Titanium.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS;
Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(reportPosition);

Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', reportPosition);
Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener('heading', reportPosition);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any more context for this question?

I have ran your exact code and received accuracy of between 10 and 183 but never any higher.

I also split it up to make sure that 'heading' wasn't calling the same method reporting bogus numbers.

I compiled against 4.1 with Ti 1.7.2 on both my simulator and iPhone 4S.

Do you have compass interference turned off? When you say you switch from google maps to your app. Are you switching or are you using an embedded map? I tried switching between maps and my app with no major change to the accuracy?

Possibly bad hardware or location? (Although that wouldn't explain why you get good results after using google maps). Do you get good results always at the start of your app and they degrade?

The obvious answer would be that you are doing nothing wrong and that you are receiving the correct level of accuracy for the location/hardware where you are using it.

Comment: since I upgraded to iOS5 the accuracy seems to be good, even though I compiled it with iOS4.3. This is the same App as I used on iOS4, I did not recompile. So don't know why, it partially seems to be going good. About google maps, not the embedded one, but the Maps App

Comment: The accuracy stays the same, not better at start. I tried different locations

Comment: I think "you're doing nothing wrong". Are you still having this issue with an iOS4 device?

Comment: yes I do still have the issue. Is there a way to boost the accuracy further? Or do i have to cope with it

Comment: To clarify -- you have 1 device with good accuracy and iOS 5 and one device with poor accuracy with iOS4? What type of device? If it's a iPhone 3G or iPad/iPad2 with only WiFi have [pseudo-GPS](http://ipod.about.com/od/ipad/a/ipad-2-faq.htm) that will likely give your poor accuracy.

Comment: it is both the same phone. iPhone 4

Comment: So you have this problem when downgrading the OS? Downgrading isn't supported.

Comment: No. I have problems with accuracy when on iOS4, and the accuracy is good on iOS5. No downgrading involved

Comment: Just to confirm, I have the exact same issue on iphone 4 with iOS5. Google maps shows perfect accuracy on start, while my Titanium app is always several streets off.

Comment: Also getting this issue.The OS maps app get's a more accurate value, but then after switching back my app starts great, and then drops to poor accuracy. Did anyone find out what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and discovered that there must be some issue with ACCURACY_BEST option.

Is weird but trying with a worse accuracy option gives me better results, just try something like this:

```
Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_NEAREST_TEN_METERS;
```

What I did then is to start with ACCURACY_NEAREST_TEN_METERS and then change it later to ACCURACY_BEST (in the first location reading).

Tried this at different locations and it starts with 65meters on first readings and goes to 10 - 5 meters later.